# How can I rephrase "the best tool that reaches every corner of the world"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm doing some proofreading of a text written by a non-native English speaker regarding a project. This text is in the project's mission statement, saying they want to create a tool that will be used globally, especially in underdeveloped countries.

I don't like this sentence, I think "the best tool that reaches every corner of the world" sounds translated, but I can't think of a better way to phrase it while conveying the same message. I thought of changing it to something like "an exceptional tool that reaches every corner of the world" but "exceptional" is not "the best". I thought of saying "the best tool for (whatever) that reaches every corner of the world" but I cannot sum up this huge program in one or two words as it has a huge number of features.

Ideally I want to be able to change "the" to "an" with an appropriate word, but any other suggestions are helpful.

Update: I wanted to upvote more answers but I apparently don't have enough reputation. There were some good suggestions, but I wanted to keep my language simple as it'll be mainly non-native speakers reading this text. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: "The best tool available anywhere (and everywhere)"?

Comment: I don't think their can be a "best" tool, best is a relative concept ( I mean in marketing sense and not product sense )and the relativity of countries is high.

Comment: The tool should have global reach OR the tool is used globally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Ideally I want to be able to change "the" to "an" with an appropriate word, but any other suggestions are helpful.

Perhaps *a global audience*?

> "the best tool... [for] a/the global audience"

Or, *yet* (implies in existence anywhere), anywhere, available anywhere...

Answer (score 4):

How about *ubiquitous*, or, *globally relevant* or *universally usable*?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

> *a [peerless](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/peerless) tool with global reach*

Answer (score 0):

You yourself just did rephrase it, for us:

> They want to create a tool that will be used globally, especially in underdeveloped countries.

You used these words to explain it to us; and they came so naturally to you, you didn't even notice. So go ahead and use these exact words to explain it to others.

As to the *best* vs. *exceptional* vs. something else, that is a red herring. The problem is not with the adjective, the problem is with the noun: *tool*. It is as vague as one could possibly get. It means nothing at all. A hammer is a tool; so is a car; so is a Java applet. So change it into something specific. If it *is* a hammer, say just that: "the best hammer that will be used globally".

Answer (score 0):

How about something with a *global impact*?